# date picker in two different browsers

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

i am workin on asp.net mvc in that i using partial views. i got one proble ie date picker is working properly on IE but it is not working on Mozilla Firefox. the i have used is:

```
<link href="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/Themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../Scripts/ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../Scripts/ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and the function on view page is:

```
          <script type="text/javascript">

                         $(document).ready(function() {
                             $("#txtTransationDate").datepicker();
                         });
                        </script>

                        <input id="txtTransationDate" name="txtTransationDate" type="text" />
```

please advice me for it. Thank in advance.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the problem? Are you receiving an error in Firefox? Is it a display issue? Tell us more!!!

Comment: Have you got it hosted somewhere for us to see?

Answer (score 0):

The code below works every time in each browser.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.0/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" 

rel="stylesheet">
<style>
input { width:300px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#txtTransationDate").datepicker();
    });
</script>
<h2>Date Picker Test</h2>
<input id="txtTransationDate" name="txtTransationDate" type="text" value="Click here to show the date picker!" />
</body>
</html>
```

So lets examine the differences between your code and this one.

- First off, i'm using the Google CDN
  for my js and css files this is
  ensuring me in the context of the
  test that my files are betting
  loaded. It also makes it easier to
  test ;)
- I'm also using jQuery 1.4.2 (latest
  version) and 1.8.2 latest jQuery UI
  version.
- The question is which version of
  jQuery are you using? and are the
  jQuery UI and jQuery versions
  compatible together for each browser?
- Your css version 1.7.x this tends to
  suggest that the jQuery UI version
  you picked up could also be newer
  than the jQuery version.
- I'm using the exact same JavaScript
  and the same input tag (with added
  attributes for the purpose of this
  test).
- It seems obvious that the problem
  does not reside in the js and html
  you provided here.
- I'm also showing you my whole
  context. Firefox is picky, IE also
  but not on the same stuff. So would
  it be possible that other js or
  malformed tags are interfering in FF?

Try running my test in a static htm page. If it works the first thing I'd try would be changing the scripts in the head for the ones I'm using.

On an other note, if you don't want or can't use the Google CDN in your final app. I suggest to use these helper methods to include css and js files. Because it's hard to foresee all the possible url levels (/) a MVC application could have.

```
/// <summary>
/// Include a javascript file.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="path"></param>
/// <param name="url"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string IncludeJavascript(this UrlHelper url, string path)
{
    return "<script src=\"" + url.Content(path) + "\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>";
}

/// <summary>
/// Include a css file.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="path"></param>
/// <param name="url"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string IncludeStylesheet(this UrlHelper url, string path)
{
    return "<link href=" + url.Content(path) + " rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />";
}
```

Usage:

```
<%= Url.IncludeJavascript("~/Scripts/jquery.js") %>
<%= Url.IncludeStylesheet("~/Scripts/Themes/jquery.css") %>
```